# Counterexample of the existence of length minimizer in Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider the Banach space  $c_0$ of all sequences that converges to $0$ with supremum norm. Let 
$$
E=\{x=(x_n)\in c_0:\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}x_n=0\}\\
r=(2,0,0,0,...)$$
How can I show that for all $x\in E$, $d(x,r) \neq d(E,r)=\inf\{d(x,r)|x\in E\}$? i.e. Length minimizer of  $r$ respect to $E$ does not exist.

Comment: Is the norm supremum norm?

Comment: Do you have any ideas about what $d(E, r)$ is equal to?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually important to first figure out the distance $d(r, E)$. Knowing this number often helps formulate a proof. In this case, we have (for reasons that we're about to see) $d(r, E) = 1$.

Consider a sequence $(x_n) \in c_0$ such that $\|x_n - r\| \le 1$. That is,
$$\max\left\lbrace |2 - x_1|, \sup_{n \ge 2} |x_n| \right\rbrace \le 1.$$
We wish to show that $(x_n) \notin E$. If this were the case, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}x_n = 0.$$
Since $|2 - x_1| \le 1$, we have $x_1 \ge 1$. We also have $x_n \ge -1$ for $n \ge 2$. So,
$$0 = \frac{x_1}{2} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^{-n} x_n \ge \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^{-n} = 0$$
Hence, the inequality is an equality. If $x_1 > 1$ or if $x_n > -1$ for some $n \ge 2$, then the inequality would have been strict, so $x_1 = 1$, and $x_n = -1$ for all $n \ge 2$. This is not possible, as $x_n \to 0$. Therefore, $x_n \notin E$.

On the other hand, for all $n, k$, let
$$x_n^k = \begin{cases}1 - 2^{-k} & \text{if } n = 1 \\ -1 & \text{if } 1 < n \le k + 1  \\ 0 & \text{if } n \ge k + 1 \end{cases}.$$
Note that, for all $k$, we have $(x_n^k)_{n=1}^\infty \in E$, and $\|x_n^k - r\| = 2^{-k} \to 0$.

Comment: Hello! Could you explain how you've shown that $d(r,E)=1$? Moreover, I'm confused about the sequence $(x_n^k)$. Isn't one supposed to show that $d(r,x)\neq d(r,E)$ for *all* sequences $x\in E$? I have a similar question and I'd be very grateful if you could clarify. There are also some typos; I believe you meant $x_n\geq -1$ for $n\geq 2$ and instead of $\frac{1}{2} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n$ you meant $\frac{1}{2} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^{-n}$.

Comment: @psie Thank you for the typos; I've corrected them. As for $d(r, E)$, you can establish $d(r, E) = 1$ by showing two things: first, that if $d(r, x) < 1$, then $x \notin E$ (i.e. $1$ is a lower bound on $\{d(r, x) : x \in E\}$, not necessarily an infimum), and that there exists a sequence $(x^k)_k \in E$ such that $d(r, x^k) \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$ (which shows that $1 + \varepsilon$ is not a lower bound on $\{d(r, x) : x \in E\}$ for $\varepsilon > 0$, i.e. that $1$ is the greatest lower bound, i.e. infimum, i.e. equal to $d(r, E)$).

Comment: @psie I ended up showing something stronger in the first part: that if $d(r, x) \le 1$, then $x \notin E$. This also shows that there is no point of minimum distance, as such a point would have to be in $E$, and be distance $1 = d(r, E)$ from $r$. I included this part of the argument while still establishing $d(r, E)$, principally to make the argument a little more elegant.